# Rudin's proof of continuity of linear transformations

Tags: analysis

In the baby Rudin, pp. 211,

> If $S$ is a metric space, if $a_{11},\dots,a_{mn}$ are real continuous functions on $S$, and if, for each $p \in S$, $A_p$ is the linear transformation of $R^n$ into $R^m$ whose matrix has entries $a_{ij}(p)$, then the mapping $p \to A_p$ is a continuous mapping of $S$ into $L(R^n,R^m)$.

The proof is:

> Suppose $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and $\{y_1,\dots,y_m\}$ are standard bases of $R^n$ and $R^m$, and $A$ is given by
>   \begin{equation*}
>   Ax = \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}c_j\right)y_i
> \end{equation*}
>   where $x = \sum_{j=1}^nc_jx_j$. The Schwarz inequality shows that
>   \begin{equation*}
>   |Ax|^2 = \sum_i\left(\sum_ja_{ij}c_j\right)^2 \le \sum_i\left(\sum_j a_{ij}^2 \cdot\sum_jc_j^2\right) = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2|x|^2
> \end{equation*}
>   Thus
>   \begin{equation}
>   \label{eq1}
>   \|A\| \le \left\{\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2\right\}^{1/2}
> \end{equation}
>   If we apply the last equation to $B - A$ in place of $A$, where $A, B \in L(R^n,R^m)$, we see that if the matrix elements $a_{ij}$ are continuous functions of a parameter, then the same is true of $A$.

I am concerned that the assumption of the standard bases may cause a problem of the proof in the general case because the change of bases causes the change of the matrix $[A]$ that corresponds to $A$, so that the last inequality may not hold. Does this proof complete as it is or just show a proof in the simple case?

Comment: the proof merely says that for a function $A :  \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ (or more generally $S \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$), if each $A_{ij}$ is continuous then $A$ is continuous for the $\|.\|_F$ norm on  $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. So all you need is checking that a change of basis won't change the fact that each $A_{ij}$ are continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get an insight of the Rudin's proof from Alex Provost's answer, but I want to see more straightforward proofs, so I made an answer by myself.

Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and $\{y_1,\dots,y_m\}$ be bases of $R^n$ and $R^m$. Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $R^n$. Define $M = \max\{|y_1|,\dots,|y_m|\}$, $x = \sum_{j=1}^n c_jx_j$, and $c = \sum_{j=1}^n c_je_j$. Then, by the Schwarz inequality,
\begin{equation}
|Ax|^2 = \left| \sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}c_j\right)y_i \right|^2 \le M^2\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2\cdot\sum_{j=1}^nc_j^2\right).
\end{equation}

Define a linear operator $X \in L(R^n)$ by $Xc = \sum_{j=1}^n c_jx_j = x$. $X$ is one-to-one because if $a = \sum_{j=1}^n a_je_j \neq \sum_{j=1}^n b_je_j = b$, then $Xa - Xb = \sum_{j=1}^n (a_j - b_j)x_j \neq 0$ by the independence of $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. So, $X$ is invertible and $c = X^{-1}x$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
|Ax|^2 \le M^2\|X^{-1}\|^2\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2 |x|^2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\|A\| \le M\|X^{-1}\|\left\{\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2\right\}^{1/2}.
\end{equation}
Since $M$ and $\|X^{-1}\|$ are finite, if we apply the last equation to $B - A$ in place of $A$, where $A, B \in L(R^n,R^m)$, we see that if the matrix elements $a_{ij}$ are continuous functions of a parameter, then the same is true of $A$.

Comment: Can you help explain the last sentence? Why we can conclude A is continuous from this inequality?

Comment: @Vector By changing $A$ to $B-A$ in the last equation, we have $\|B-A\|\le M\|X^{-1}\|\left\{\sum_{i,j}(b_{ij}-a_{ij})^2\right\}^{1/2}$. Thus, we can make $\|B-A\|$ arbitrarily small by letting $b_{ij}$ sufficiently close to $a_{ij}$ for all $i,j$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is complete as it is. The author specifically states higher up that he is going to work with fixed bases. Also, since he is working with $L(R^n,R^m)$ instead of a general $L(X,Y)$, you may consider the standard bases to have *already* been fixed, as a pair of identifications $X \cong R^n$, $Y \cong R^m$ amounts to mapping any bases of $X,Y$ to the standard bases of $R^n,R^m$ through linear isomorphisms.

It is convenient to choose the standard bases because this choice allows one to treat linear maps in $L(R^n,R^m)$ as matrices *in such a way that the action of a linear map $A$ on a vector $v \in R^n$ coincides with the result of the matrix product $Av \in R^m$*.

Comment: Thanks Alex Provost. It was helpful.